# NSTextfield and user inputted regex

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsstring, nstextfield

Is there an easy way to take a user inputted `NSString` from an `NSTextfield`, and convert it to a valid `objc regex`?

I would like to escape all the '\' characters, but obviously not all the unneeded ones, i.e.... '\n', ' \xA9', '\r' etc....

for example this:

```
NSString *rejectString = @"^Steve\-Smi+.*+(\n)?"
```

needs to become this:

```
@"^Steve\\-Smi+.*+(\n)?"
```

Comment: make sure this is needed, because escapes aren't needed when you aren't interpreting constants... ie @"\\" is the same as field.stringValue when the field has a single backslash

Comment: not to confuse or contradict, but to match a backslash the regex string would be@"\\\\" or in a text field "\\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up using NSPredicate instead, its much more user friendly:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: ojb1, obj2, obj3, obj4, nil];
NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [NSMutableArray new];
NSString *ignoreString = [ignoreStringTextfield stringValue];

for (NSString *name in array)
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF MATCHES %@)", ignoreString];
    if ([predicate evaluateWithObject:name])
        [filteredArray addObject:name];
}
return filteredArray;
```